# Problema usando RotativaPdf no aspnet core 3

Tags: asp.net-core

Tenho seguido as configurações recomendadas na documentação, realizei várias pesquisas, não tenho erro no exemplo mais o relatório não e gerado. Inicialmente fiz a instalação do :

```
Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.2.0-beta
```

Configuração do Startup

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

Exemplo do meu controller Home (Dentro da pasta Home, eu tenho uma View com o nome = VisualizarPDF)

```
  public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


public IActionResult RotativaPDF()
{
    Person person = new Person()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Primeiro",
        LastName = "Ultimo"
    };


    var relatorioPDF = new ViewAsPdf
    {
        ViewName = "VisualizarPDF",
        IsGrayScale = false,
        FileName = "Fornecedor.pdf",
        PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
        PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
        Model = person
    };

    return relatorioPDF;
}


public IActionResult Index()
{
    RotativaPDF();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução e instalar a versão

```
Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.1.1
```

No Startup basta fazer a configuração:

```
//Configuração do rotativa
            RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env2, "Rotativa");
```

Altera:

```
   [Obsolete]
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env2)
```

Isso resolve o problema